# How to constrain transitions like keeping an animated component visible?

Tags: codenameone

With `com.codename1.ui.Container.animateLayout(int)`, transitions and such the layout of a Form can be animated - this is nice.

Assume a Container instance, scrollable in the Y-axis which contains components A and B where A is only visible in its last third because the scrollable container it sits in is scrolled down. If then the component A changes its size to one third of its previous size and `animateLayout(durationInMillis)` is called the component A animates out of view. I'd like to constrain the scrollY attribute in a way that component A stays visible.

Do You have any idea how this could be done? Is there a way to enforce such constraints during an animation and, if not, could it be done?

Comment: What about `Container.scrollComponentToVisible(...)`?

Comment: Yes, that could be used. But when would that be called. After the transition, but how. And then the Component would animate away and then reappear. Maybe it would be better to prevent scrollY from changing until animateLayout has finished and only then initiate tensile scrolling if necessary.

Comment: Actually being able to lock scrollY would solve several issues I am having with scrollable containers. With trees for example it is not a good behavior to scroll abruptly when closing a branch. I think it would be much nicer to have it animating slowly into place then.

Comment: The only way to achieve this with the current API is to override `setScrollX/Y`. Scrolling could probably be considered by the animate layout implementation but it's not something we implemented yet